# "How to Resolve 'Could not find or load main class' Error when Running Java Code to Generate Sub-classes in Specific Directory"

Tags: java

I was trying to run this java code as a script to generate sub-classes in  /home/ankit/Dev/Zealot/com/piscan/Zealot directory. But it is not running and constantly giving the same error.

This is the error:

```
cd "/home/ankit/Dev/Zealot/com/piscan/tool/" && javac GenerateAst.java && java GenerateAst
```

Error: Could not find or load main class GenerateAst
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: GenerateAst (wrong name: com/piscan/tool/GenerateAst)

Here's the code for reference:

```
package com.piscan.tool;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


// this code will generate sytanx tree subclasses 
public class GenerateAst {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            System.out.println("Usage: generate_ast <output directory>");
            System.exit(64);
        }
        String outputDir = args[0];
        defineAst(outputDir, "Expr", Arrays.asList(
                "Binary : Expr left , Token operator, Expr right",
                "Grouping : Expr expression",
                "Literal : Object value",
                "Unary : Token operator, Expr right"));
    }

    // this will create a new file expr.java and put the basic code there
    private static void defineAst(String outputDir, String baseName, List<String> types) throws IOException {
        String path = outputDir + "/" + baseName + ".java";
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");

        writer.println("package com.piscan.Zealot;");
        writer.println();
        writer.println("import java.util.List;");
        writer.println();
        writer.println("abstract class " + baseName + "{");

        /*
         * When we call this, baseName is “Expr”, which is both the name of the class
         * and the name of the file it outputs. We pass this as an argument instead of
         * hardcoding the name because we’ll add a separate family of classes later for
         * statements.
         */
        // The AST classes
        for (String type : types) {
            String className = type.split(":")[0].trim();
            String fields = type.split(":")[1].trim();
            defineType(writer, baseName, className, fields);

        }

        writer.println("}");
        writer.close();
    }

    private static void defineType(PrintWriter writer, String baseName, String className, String fieldList) {
        writer.println("  static class " + className + " extends " + baseName + " {");

        // constructor
        writer.println("    " + className + "(" + fieldList + ") {");

        // Store parameters in fields.
        String[] fields = fieldList.split(", ");
        for (String field : fields) {
            String name = field.split(" ")[1];
            writer.println("      this." + name + " = " + name + ";");
        }

        writer.println("    }");

        // Fields.
        writer.println();
        for (String field : fields) {
            writer.println("    final " + field + ";");
        }

        writer.println("  }");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using full packagename.

```
cd "/home/ankit/Dev/Zealot/com/piscan/tool/" && javac GenerateAst.java && java com.piscan.tool.GenerateAst
```

Also, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean). It is most probably the way you are writing
`java <class-name>` command

Comment: I already tried using full packagename but it's still not working.